# Find all the complex solutions to $\bar z$=z?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am not really sure how to approach this question. Any pointers in the right direction would be great. Thanks

Comment: read the definition of complex conjugation

Comment: It would be good if you gave some background about what you know as well as anything you might have tried (I assume you have had some thoughts on the question...)

Answer (score 1):

Set $z=a+ib\implies \bar z=a-ib$

So,we  need $a+ib=a-ib\iff b=0$

Comment: So basically z is real? Is that what theyre asking for? Thanks for the help

Comment: @user136024, exactly. A related Question can be $z=-\bar z$

Answer (score 1):

Geometric reasoning: the conjugation is the symmetry about the horizontal axis, that fixes the points in the horizontal axis and moves all the other points.